# Localizing script to pass a value to a javascript function

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script, wp-localize-script

i'm really getting crazy about this. after hours of trials, i can't get out of this.

I'm trying to pass a php variable value to an enqueued jquery script but i can't.

here is my code.

php :

```
function itinerary_enqueuescripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('itenqueue', JSONURL.'/js/loadjson.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script( 'itenqueue', 'itajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => "hithere" ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'itinerary_enqueuescripts');
```

in my loadjson.js file i have a simple

```
var _latitude = 43.309; 
var _longitude = 8.499;
var jsonPath = itajax.ajaxurl; //and should transform, in this example, in hithere
```

But when the script is enqueued, the var jsonPath as the value of itajax.ajaxurl :)

The scripts gets enqueued correctly, in this example i make a simple variable declaration (just to let out problems.. e.g. the script gets enqueued too early).

Funny thing (and perhaps here's the clue, this is quite a copy/paste from another plugin of mine, for a function that points to admin-ajax.php for front end posting. It's the same syntax, with different variable names of course, but in this case it doesn't work).

Thanks for any clue. (i tried quite anything, registering-localizing-enqueueing, enqueueing in wp_footer at the very last.. even changing double qoutes to single quotes :) Now i suppose i really must miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS variables are not directly replaced as you are expecting. Localizing in your code is correct.

When you do `var jsonPath = itajax.ajaxurl;`, value of `itajax.ajaxurl` is assigned to the variable `jsonPath`.

If you debug this variable in the console, you will get the correct value.
`console.log(jsonPath);`

Comment: of course.. wordpress adds the variable as a global scope var!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add `__` before your variable value, try this code:

```
wp_localize_script('itenqueue', 'itajax', array(
    'ajaxurl' => __('hi there')
)
```